# How to calculate MSBuild property before import

Tags: visual-studio, msbuild

Consider these two [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Msbuild) files. First `build-script.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- build-script.xml -->
<Project
    ToolsVersion="4.0"
    DefaultTargets="Build"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputName>OutputName</OutputName>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Import Project="build-script-to-import.xml"/>
</Project>
```

and then `build-script-to-import.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!-- build-script-to-import.xml -->
<Project
    ToolsVersion="4.0"
    DefaultTargets="Build"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

    <PropertyGroup>
        <OutputPath>Path\$(OutputName)</OutputPath>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <Target Name="Build">
        <Message Text="$(OutputPath)" />
    </Target>
</Project>
```

These two files represents a *very* simplified C# project file (`build-script.xml`) referencing a common targets file (`build-script-to-import.xml`). That means that it is not an option to change the `build-script-to-import.xml` file. The problem is that the `OutputName` is calculated, and I need to set it to this calculated value before I import the `build-script-to-import.xml` file. Do you know how I can accomplish this?

---

NOTE 1: The calculated value is in fact an assembly version which I am able to fetch from an assembly file with the [`GetAssemblyIdentity` MSBuild task](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164296). The problem as I see it is that I may not call a target before the import happens. I would like to set the value for property `OutputName` with the help of the `GetAssemblyIdentity` MSBuild task.

NOTE 2: The build will be triggered by Visual Studio, so I may not use a batch file and send a property to MSBuild as a command line argument.

Answer (score 0):

Move the declaration of $(OutputPath) inside your "Build" target.  The only way to use "calculated" properties is to have them evaluated inside a target.  Globally declared "static" properties will always be evaluated before any target runs, and presumably you need to run a target to calculate the value of $(OutputName).  Just be sure your name calculating target runs before the "Build" target.

Comment: The problem is that property `OutputName` in file `build-script.xml` is used throughout `build-script-to-import.xml`, which in fact represents the Visual Studio WiX project common targets file in my example. So then I would need to move all properties that depend on `OutputName` into a target in my file `build-script.xml`. The WiX targets file is huge like the `Microsoft.Common.targets` in the .NET framework directory. Hope there is another option.

Comment: You can move it inside an InitialTarget, which will always evaluate prio to other targets, but only if the property is not referenced in other static declarations.

Comment: As far as I can see the property evaluation in `build-script-to-import.xml` will happen before my initial targets in `build-script.xml` are executed. Then dependent properties in `build-script-to-import.xml` will have values based on the static value in `build-script.xml` set before initial targets are executed in `build-script.xml`.

Answer (score 0):

If Corresponding targets from imported project allows to **modify `DependsOnTargets`**

```
<Target Name="Build" DependsOnTargets="@(BuildDependsOn)" />
```

you can modify Item and add your target wich will prepare needed properties.

If it is not possible you can **write wrapper** to call underlying target/targets (Build/Rebuild/Clean) by yourself (without importing `build-script-to-import.xml`):

**build-script.xml**

```
 <Target Name="Build" DependsOn="PrepareProperties">
      <MSBuild Projects="build-script-to-import.xml"  
               Targets="Build"            
               Properties="OutputName=$(OutputName);$(OtherProperties)"/>
 </Target>
```

**Suggestion**

Depends on your requirement to dynamically change `OutputName` there may be mach simpler solution. Just not to do it. It is rather simpler to write your own custom build step to copy from fixed output directory to your destination wich is calculated using your rules.

For example, I prefer practice when I have directory called **latest** with fixed path and a directory for each version of product. Every one can take latest version from that folder.

Comment: I may not change the imported targets file (`build-script-to-import.xml`). It is not written by me. There is a lot of project items, project references and such that I need to send to your suggested `MSBuild` task. It would be easier just to redeclare all properties inside a before build target as suggested by [Brian Kretzler](http://stackoverflow.com/users/610674/brian-kretzler). I don't think `DependsOn` attribute is a valid attribute on the `Target` element in your last example.

Comment: It is not so simple. It looks like a very fragile solution, as well as mine. But it's just variants. I've updated my answer to propose more reliable solution.